# How make Autocomplete in JsHelper?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, autocomplete

How make a Ajax Autocomplete in 'pure' JsHelper? Is possible?

Thanks,
Celso

Answer (score 1):

You might find http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/CakePHP-1-3-JSHelper-and-Autocomplete-Missing-method-td3270384.html useful.

Comment: this is very cool but...only to JqueryEngine...Unfortunately Mootools (i believe) dont have a "core" autocomplete...

Comment: I'm going to take a complete shot in the dark with http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/